# How to use `LIKE` operator as a column in `SQL`?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to use `LIKE` operator as a column such:

```
SELECT name, (name LIKE '%flow%') AS bool1
FROM table1
WHERE ...
```

and get the result such:

```
name                 bool1
--------------     ----------
over flow              1
stack over flow        1
stack over             0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select name, case when name like '%flow%' then 1 else 0 end as bool1 
from table1 
where...
```